# Change database connection and update datagridview

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm trying to display the database records after changing connection string data source. Here's my code:

```
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + connFile + "; Version=3; FailIfMissing=True; Foreign Keys=True;");
getTable("SELECT * FROM tbl_programs WHERE int_is" +
    lastDisplayedBuild.ToString() +
    "=1 ORDER BY txt_programName;");
```

And my global variables are:

```
private SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
private SQLiteDataAdapter sqliteDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
private BindingSource bindingSource = null;
```

How can I display new records in datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used this function to

```
public DataTable getData(string sqlCommand)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (var con = new SQLiteConnection { ConnectionString = "your connection string" })
    {
       using (var command = new SQLiteCommand { Connection = con })
       {
           if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
               con.Close();

           con.Open();
           command.CommandText = sqlCommand;

           dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

       }
       return dt;
    }
 }


//Call to load your Data
public void loadData()
{
   this.DatagridView.DataSource = getData("Command string here");
}
```